# how to do ajax or jquery with django1.3

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, python-2.7

I am absolutely new to django framework and new to web development and python. Currently I'm trying to implement ajax in my project. I am not able to find any working sample. I need help with putting **ajax** or **jquery** in a **django1.3** project.

Now I'm trying to implement ajax using dojango' app. I install it successfully and trying [this tutorial](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=312).

urls.py:

```
(r'^dojango/', include('dojango.urls')),
(r'^simple/', 'views.simple'),
(r'^simple-ajax-set/', 'views.simple_ajax_set'),
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from dojango.decorators import json_response
@expect_post_request
@json_response
def simple_ajax_set(request):
    ret = {}
    firstname = request.POST['firstname']
    surname = request.POST['surname']
    if len(surname)<3:
        ret['error'] = 'Surname is too short.'
        ret['success'] = False
    if ret['success']:
        # Store the data here
        pass
    return ret
```

simple.html

```
{% extends "dojango/base.html" %} 
{% block dojango_page_title %}Simple AJAX with dojango{% endblock %}
{% block dojango_header_extra %}
<script type="text/javascript">
function userFormSubmit(){
 var form = dojo.byId("userForm");
 dojo.xhrPost({url:form.action,
  handleAs:"json",
  content:{surname:form.surname.value,
   firstname:form.firstname.value
  },
  load:function(response, ioArgs){
   if (response.success){
    dojo.byId("info").innerHTML = "Submitted successfully";
   } else {
    dojo.byId("info").innerHTML = "Error: "+response.error;
   }
  },
  error:function(data){ // This happens on a 500 error or alikes.
   dojo.byId("info").innerHTML = "Error sending data.";
  }
 });
}
 </script>

{% endblock %}

{% block dojango_content %}
 <form id="userForm" onsubmit="userFormSubmit(); return false;" action="/simple-ajax-set/">
  First name: <input id="firstname" /><br />
  Surname: <input id="surname" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <span id="info"></span>
 </form>
{% endblock %}
```

When I run I got the exception

```
NameError at /simple-ajax-set/
name 'expect_post_request' is not defined
```

So I change my code as in the first part of the above tutorial, and I got the following  exception

```
 'MultiValueDictKeyError at /simple-ajax-set/' , "Key 'firstname' not found in <QueryDict: {}>" when click on the submit button at simple.html.
```

Please help me to find out the problem sand also share some links or codes containg ajax/jquery which works with django1.3. and python 2.7,

Can any one suggest working a hello world ajax or jquery example for django1.3?

Comment: when I try firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
    surname = request.POST.get('surname'),it returned Document contents:
{}&& {"success": true},But there is a message "There was an error parsing the JSON document. The document may not be well-formed."

Comment: This example looks like you are using Dojo not jQuery.

Comment: Yea @Mark Lavin ,I make use of the project Dojango.

Comment: @Mark Lavin, am In big problem I am trying to do jquery or dojo etc for last couple of weeks.But am failed.My doubt is ,If I use Jquery,How can I call a python function from my Jquery's ready function(from a template).Can you help me by share yor ideas or any links.I tried a lot of links from google ,But am failed. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend taking a lot at Dajax: http://dajaxproject.com/

Answer (score 0):

"Pure" jQuery and django [here](http://webcloud.se/log/AJAX-in-Django-with-jQuery/). That made me happy when i was on your place. Good luck!